# "soft match/merge" of 2 different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data sets. Below is a sample representation of the 2 datasets (the actual data sets have approximately 9000 rows of data).

```
Ds01=pd.dataframe({
    ‘name’:[‘James', 'Henry', 'Abe', 'Brian', 'Claude']
    ‘ID’:[1001, 1234,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A]
    ‘Amount’:[10000, 15000, 350000, 45000000, 400]
})

Ds02=pd.dataframe({
    Name:[john,James,321account,’Briane’,’Klaud’]
    ID:[12,3467,854345,76457,976234]
})
```

I want to fill #N/A in Ds01 from Ds02 for the ID column.
Is there a way in python to do a “soft match”? I have used merge in pandas. But that does not match unless the name is exact match. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you mean by 'soft match' with the data you illustrated in these data sets?

Answer (score 0):

I think `pd.merge(Ds01,Ds02,how="outer")` should work.